# How to compare 2 timestamp

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<div class="unit-date" dateorder="{{gar.dateorder}}">{{gar.dateorder}}</div>
```

There is a timestamp in each of the data unit. I want to compare 2 of them which if created earlier.
The date time stamp format is like `2015-02-18-14.08.31.532368`, it includes some *dots* there.
I wrote like below:

```
it('Compare the date time', function() {
 var datelist1 = element.all(by.binding('gar.dateorder')).get(0).getText();
 var datelist2 = element.all(by.binding('gar.dateorder')).get(1).getText();
 //expect(datelist1).toBe('2015-02-18-14.08.31.532368');
 //expect(datelist2).toBe('2015-02-18-14.08.31.465582');
 //datelist1 -datelist2 >0 ?;
});
```

How could I use the bottom expression? current elements return *string*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the format of the date strings, you can parse them and get their values:

```
function dateValue(str) {
  return new Date(str.replace(/\-(\d+)\.(\d+)\./, " $1:$2:")).valueOf();
}
```

Then your last line can be evaluated with:

```
expect(dateValue(datelist1)).toBeGreaterThan(dateValue(datelist2));
```